# Java-error al ejecutarse (dateTimeException)

Tags: java, poo, datetime, excepciones

Estoy realizando un ejercicio orientado a la gestion del tiempo, he realizado este menú para guardar los datos del usuario, pero al terminar de introducir los datos me salta error dateTimeException, he tratado de saber porque no me devuelve nada segun el debugger pero no termino de entender que esta fallando.

**Menu**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String email;
        String phoneNumber;
        String password;

        System.out.println("Introduzca su nombre:");
        firstName = lector.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduzca su apellido:");
        lastName = lector.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduzca su email:");
        email = lector.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Indique su numero de telefono:");
        phoneNumber = lector.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduzca una contrasenya:");
        password = lector.nextLine();

        Persona personas = new Persona(firstName,lastName,fechaCumple(),email,phoneNumber,password);

        System.out.println(personas.toString());

    }

    public static LocalDate fechaCumple() {
        int any,mes,dia;

        System.out.println("Cual es la fecha de su cumpleanyos?\nIntroduzca el anyo:(yyyy)");
        any = lector.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Introduzca el mes:(MM)");
        mes = lector.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Introduzca el dia:(dd)");
        dia = lector.nextInt();
        lector.nextLine(); //limpiar memoria

        return LocalDate.of(any, mes, dia);

    }

}
```

Constructor de la clase persona:

```
public Persona(String firstName, String lastName, LocalDate birthday, String email, String phoneNumber, String password) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.createdOn = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.password = password;
    }
```

Metodos de la clase Persona:

```
public int getAge() {

        LocalDate hoy = LocalDate.now();
        Period periodo = Period.between(this.birthday, hoy);

        return periodo.getYears();

    }

    public boolean isNewUser() {
        LocalDate hoy = LocalDate.now();
        Duration tiempoRegistro = Duration.between(this.createdOn, hoy);

        return (tiempoRegistro.toDays() < 15 ); 
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "* Nombre: " + firstName + "\n* Apellido: " + lastName + "\n* Cumpleaños: " + birthday + "\n* Email: "
                + email + "\n* Numero de telefono: " + phoneNumber + "\n* Fecha de registro: " + createdOn + "\n* Contrasenya: " + password
                + "\n* Salt: " + salt + "\n* Edad: " + getAge() + "\n* Nuevo Usuario?: " + isNewUser();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema esta en el metodo isNewUser que es llamado por el metodo toString, el conflicto esta en el tipo de dato que le estas pasando a la funcion  Duration.between

```
public boolean isNewUser() {
    LocalDate hoy = LocalDate.now();
    Duration tiempoRegistro = Duration.between(this.createdOn, hoy);

    return (tiempoRegistro.toDays() < 15 ); 
}
```

EL segundo parametro que le pasas es de tipo LocalDate, cuando ambos parametros deberia ser de tipo LocalDateTime.

```
public boolean isNewUser() {
    LocalDateTime hoy = LocalDateTime.now();
    Duration tiempoRegistro = Duration.between(this.createdOn, hoy);

    return (tiempoRegistro.toDays() < 15);
}
```

De esta manera resolverias el problema de tu excepcion aun que en lo particular la logica tu metodo isNewUser me parece algo incorrecta pero ese ya es otro tema.

Saludos..

Comment: Hola JGarnica! muchisimas gracias justo era eso!! no sabia porque era no sabia que era lo que me fallaba, mmm porque es algo incorrecta te importaria explicarme?

Comment: Quizas no entendi bien tu  logica pero el metodo isNewUser no parece que pertenezca  a la clase Persona y mas bien estaria dentro una clase de utileria o una clase que este dentro de la capa de datos( base datos y ORM)  y no en tu modelo/pojo ya que en mi opinion este solo deberia representar los atributos del objeto y no llevar logica de negocios dentro de ella, ya que supongo que  ese metodo tu lo usaras para comparar contra una base de datos y checar hace cuantos dias el usuario fue registrado.

Comment: Pero igual a lo mejor estoy exagerando y la estructura que tienes te basta :)

Comment: Ah ya entiendo jeje muchas gracias por explicarme jeje el caso es que aun no he tocado bases de datos con java y el ejercicio tenia un diagrama uml con estos metodos dentro, yo debia rellenarlo y pensar como hacerlo jeje igualmente muchísimas gracias! Cuando empieze con este tema lo tendré muy en cuenta de colocarlo en la clase adecuada :)